# After extending User profile to include a Profile model, Django throws UNIQUE Constraint Failed error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I extended the User model to include a profile with the following code:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    PTO_TIER_CHOICES = (
        (200.0, 'Boss 5-10 Years'),
        (160.0, 'Boss 2-5 Years'),
        (120.0, 'Boss 0-2 Years'),
        (160.0, 'Peon 5-10 Years'),
        (120.0, 'Peon 2-5 Years'),
        (90.0, 'Peon 0-2 Years'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pto_tier = models.FloatField(choices=PTO_TIER_CHOICES, default=90.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

I also created a LeaveHistory model with a foreign key to the User model with the following code:

```
class LeaveHistory(models.Model):
    LEAVE_CHOICES = (
        (True, 'PTO'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Jury Duty'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Voting'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Military Leave'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Bereavement'), #is chargeable?
        (True, 'Emergency'), #is chargeable?
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leave_start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    leave_end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    leave_type = models.BooleanField(choices=LEAVE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

The problem that I am having is that whenever I try to create more than one LeaveHistories with the same username I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/accounts/leavehistory/add/
UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_leavehistory.user_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/accounts/leavehistory/add/
Django Version: 1.10.3
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_leavehistory.user_id
Exception Location: C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 337
Python Executable:  C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\django projects\\company_projects',
 'C:\\Users\\achesley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\python35.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\achesley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\achesley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\achesley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32',
 'C:\\Users\\achesley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 20 Dec 2016 16:03:13 -0700

Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/accounts/leavehistory/add/

Django Version: 1.10.3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'accounts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  337.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_leavehistory.user_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  544.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  211.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in add_view
  1509.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\contextlib.py" in inner
  30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1449.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in save_model
  1007.         obj.save()

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  796.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  824.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  908.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  947.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1045.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1054.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  337.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /admin/accounts/leavehistory/add/
Exception Value: UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_leavehistory.user_id
```

I know it probably has something to do with extending the User model because I tried it on another project where the User model hadn't been extended and it worked fine. If you need any other code snippets or clarification let me know, thank you.

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: Error not consistent with your models. Please post the exact error strack trace if you want help

Comment: @selcuk I ran makemigrations and migrate which didn't solve the problem. I then flushed the database and started from scratch, it still didn't work.

Comment: @e4c5 I'll post the complete stack trace tomorrow morning.

Comment: The `LeaveHistory` model you posted has no unique constraint on `User`, so the traceback cannot be triggered by this code. Please post the __real__ code - or the real traceback. In any way, if that's the real traceback, it clearly mentions a UNIQUE constraint violation on  "accounts_leavehistory.user_id" so it has nothing to do with your `Profile` model.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I posted the full stack trace.

Comment: @AaronChesley if that's the correct traceback then either your code snippet (the one with the `LeaveHistory` model) is incorrect or incomplete (if so please post the full model code) or you changed the model (removing something that created this UNIQUE constraint) and didn't correctly updated your db schema with migrations.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Now that you mention it the LeaveHistory model use to have a OneToOne relationship to the User: user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) but I changed it to a ForeignKey. I've completely dropped the database though and ran makemigrations/migrate but that still didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @AaronChesley then either there's a problem with your migrations or you're not working on the right database. Problem solved.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You were right Bruno, my migrations weren't working. Thank you for leading me down the correct path. I thought running "makemigrations" would find changes in any of my installed apps but I had to specify the app name like "makemigrations accounts"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the LeaveHistory model from:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

to:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but I wasn't applying the migrations correctly which resulted in my UNIQUE Constraint Error.
I kept running

**python manage.py makemigrations**

which didn't detect any new changes in my **accounts** app. The correct way that worked for me was to specify the app name in the makemigrations command,

**python manage.py makemigrations [app name]**,

which detected the changes and I could then run **python manage.py migrate** and it succesfully applied the changes to my database.

Answer (score -2):

That is because you are linking LeaveHistory to the User model via foreign key. Instead, you should be linking to the Profile model.

```
class LeaveHistory(models.Model):
   ...
   profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: And how is that going to solve the problem? `Profile` and `User` are linked to each other through a OneToOne relation anyway.

Comment: User is meant to be used in an abstract way so that it is not linked to things that relate specifically to an application. That is why you create a Profile model so that it can be used as a 'middle-man'. 

User model is default in Django auth system and I believe it is constrained so foreign key must be unique in the related table. So in your case, you can only have one User reference to a LeaveHistory instance, and cannot create another with the same user.

I don't think you will encounter this problem with Profile.

Comment: This is pure speculation and not related to the issue in the question. `User` is not an abstract model and there is no magical way to _constrain_ a foreign key **in another model** to be unique, unless the child model is defined as such. The OP probably defined the `user` fk to be unique, or as a 1-to-1 field but then forgot to migrate the database schema.

Comment: @zubhav I tried linking to profile but if I remember right I got the same error. I'll try it again tomorrow morning and let you know for sure. Thanks for your time so far.

Comment: @AaronChesley read Selcuk's comment - he's the one being right here.

Comment: @zubhav Django is open source, so don't "believe" - read the code, test, and make sure... Of course `User` is a concrete model and of course you can set how many foreign keys on `User` as you whish.